# how can we print only the last item from for loop? python 3.?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime(2000,9,17)
for i in range(50): 
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(date)
```

I want to print only the last date in the form 2075-01-30 and Not as 2075-01-30 00:00:00

Comment: unindent `print(date)`

Comment: @StephenRauch thank you , how to remove 00:00:00?

Comment: You probably want to use a `date` rather than a `datetime`. But if you actually do want to do the calculations on `datetime`, you can either convert to `date` at the end, or use `strftime` to print the `datetime` in whatever format you want, including one that ignore the time bits.

Comment: I'm assuming this is just a simplified [mcve], and in your real code you're doing something a bit more complicated. But just in case: you realize you can add `timedelta(days=50)`, or `50 * timedelta(days=1)` without a loop, right?

Answer (score 1):

Unindent the print statement in the last line

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime(2000,9,17)
for i in range(50): 
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(date)
```

Comment: I'm surprised also. This isn't as good as Steven's answer for this exact task but is a great general solution. Perhaps mentioning that module variables retain their last value when the for exits.

Comment: @tdelaney Why mention that? This variable existed before the loop, so nobody expecting C-style block scoping would be confused here. (I ask because, if I'm missing something confusing here, my answer probably needs it just as much as Jai's does.)

Comment: You didn't say why it works and I think that since this question is obviously from someone new to python, a quick explanation is helpful. We don't have to go to first principles for everything, but that's the "a-ha" OP needed.

Answer (score 1):

To not print the date every time, you just need to move the `print` outside the loop by unindenting it, as Stephen Rauch explained.

If you want print just the date instead of the date and time, you probably actually want to use a [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object instead of a `datetime` object:

```
date = datetime.date(2000,9,17)
for i in range(50): 
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(date)
```

---

If there's some reason you actually want to use a `datetime` for your intermediate calculations (which may have implications for weird cases like daylight saving transitions, which maybe you've thought through and want?), you can instead convert to `date` only at the end, or print any format you want with [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
date = datetime.datetime(2000,9,17)
for i in range(50): 
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But if not, it's simpler to just use `date`.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done simply as:

```
import datetime as dt
date_str = dt.datetime(2000, 9, 17) + dt.timedelta(days=50)
print(date_str.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

#### Result:

```
2000-11-06
```